# Get the Post with highest score for each user

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

Given these 2 table:

Users:

```
Name    UserId  
-----------
Pump 1  1   
Pump 1  2
Pump 1  3
Pump 2  4
Pump 2  5
Pump 2  6
```

Posts:

```
PostId      UserId  Score

1           3       5
2           1       8
3           3       3
4           1       2
5           2       8
6           2       1
```

How do I get the post with the highest score made by each users?

Best I can do is:

```
select Users.UserId as UserID, Posts.PostId as PostsID, Max(Posts.Score) as Score
from Users
inner join Posts on Posts.UserId = Users.UserId
Group by Users.UserId, Posts.PostsId
```

which doesn't gave me the wrong answer.

Comment: Which RDBMS? MySQL or SQL-server? Also, this is probably the single most frequently asked question asked here under those tags.

Comment: ...and where is your `ORDER BY Posts.Score DESC` clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62a4fb/6)**

```
SELECT u.Name,
       u.UserId,
       p.PostId,
       p.Score
FROM Users u
  JOIN Posts p
    ON p.UserId = u.UserId
  LEFT JOIN Posts p1
    ON p1.UserId = p.UserId
    AND p1.Score > p.Score
WHERE p1.Score is null
```

Result:

```
|   NAME | USERID | POSTID | SCORE |
|--------|--------|--------|-------|
| Pump 1 |      3 |      1 |     5 |
| Pump 1 |      1 |      2 |     8 |
| Pump 1 |      2 |      5 |     8 |
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using SQL-Server you can use a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER` or `DENSE_RANK`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT u.UserId as UserID, p.PostId as PostsID, p.Score,
         RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.UserId  ORDER BY Score DESC)
  FROM dbo.Users u
  INNER JOIN dbo.Posts p on p.UserId = u.UserId
)
SELECT UserID, PostsID, Score
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/947cd/2/0)</kbd>

In MySql this should work:

```
SELECT Users.userid     AS UserID, 
       Posts.postid     AS PostsID, 
       Max(Posts.score) AS Score 
FROM   Users 
       INNER JOIN Posts 
               ON Posts.userid = Users.userid 
GROUP  BY Users.userid
```

Although the `PostID` is somewhat arbitrary here.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19f8a/1/0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

```
Select T.PostId,
       S.UserID,
       S.MAXSCORES
From TBL1 T INNER JOIN 
(SELECT MAX(SCORE) MAXSCORES
           ,UserID
     FROM TBL1 Group BY UserID) S On
S.UserID= t.UserID and s.MAXSCORES= t.score;
```

## [Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb8a6/10)

Answer (score 1):

You need only table Posts to select this result.

```
select p1.UserId, p1.PostId, p1.Score
from Posts p1
--  inner join Users u on p1.UserId = u.UserId
where not exists 
   (select * 
    from Posts p2 
    where p1.UserId = p2.UserId and p1.Score < p2.Score);
```